# Просклонять слово в golang

Tags: golang, морфология

Подскажите готовые решения для того чтобы из слова роман получить список слов

```
кто, что?       И:  роман   романы
кого, чего?     Р:  романа  романов
кому, чему?     Д:  роману  романам
кого, что?      В:  роман   романы
кем, чем?       Т:  романом романами
о ком, о чём?   П:  о романе    о романах
где?            М:  в романе    в романах
```

Раньше был сервис ЯндексюСпеллер, но сейчас я почему-то [не нашел](https://export.yandex.ru/inflect.xml?name=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC) доступа к нему.
Склонять по падежам надо на русском языке:)

Comment: Я такое пользовал https://github.com/striker2000/petrovich